# Rename origin to default (git)

Tags: git

I accidentally renamed the origin to `master`, and since the git upstream branch defaults to `origin/master`, I have to pull like this: `git pull master master` or `git pull master dev`.

How could I rename it back, so that I could pull the current branch with just `git pull`?

```
~$ git remote rename master origin
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Comment: You probably have both remote `master` and `origin` (possibly duplicates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in the directory `.git` of your repository and modify manually your file `config`:

`[remote "master"]` => `[remote "origin"]`

Comment: I guess I had the same remote with two different names. I've removed the master one from the config file, and `git pull` behaviour is restored now.

Comment: Indeed, this is a reason for what was happening.

Comment: @RápliAndrás Of course, you can always change your configuration by editing the Git config file(s) manually, as in Gnucki's answer. However, by doing so, it's relatively easy to accidentally corrupt your config file. For that reason, you should endeavor using Git commands as much as possible instead of editing the config file(s) manually. Git offers commands for everything you're likely to need to solve your problem; use them! For more details, see the [`git-remote` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html).